# Is there a way to generate a pseudo-random number inside a contract in liquidity?

Tags: smart-contracts, protocol, liquidity

If I require a pseudo-random number (PRN) in the internal working of a function in liquidity, is there a way to do it? Is there one in Michelson?
I already know about the way to send a PRN through RPC call, but I'm looking for  something that can be applied inside a function.

Comment: Of course you can do it. You can for example directly implement some simple PRNG in Michelson/Liquidity, or use the hash instructions (BLAKE2B/Crypto.blake2b etc). But you probably shouldn't... Why do you want pseudorandomness?

Comment: I am not planning to use it for security purposes so probably I will create my own "somewhat-PRNG". My main need was to sample unique strings from a random sample space to serve as ID values and I was looking for a possible solution for that. Is there another way to generate UIDs that are 'random looking'?

Comment: Can you explain why you need these IDs and what you are trying to do with them? There likely is a better way.

Answer (score 11):

If what you mean is a non-predictable source of randomness, no, there is none. Any information that could be used for that could either be predictable by a user, or tempered by a malicious baker.

You should probably use an external source of randomness, as the oracle presented in [here](http://www.ocamlpro.com/2018/11/06/liquidity-tutorial-a-game-with-an-oracle-for-random-numbers/).

An improvement of that would be to use commitments, i.e. the oracle would push a hash in the contract before the game, and send the random number (and a nonce) after the game, the contract checking that the hash and the random number match (with the nonce). Commitments prevent oracles from changing the random number during the game...